# get_terms() category cards wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

So i am wondering what's wrong with my code for it to act this way. I am trying to loop through my categories and display them in separate cards. I am getting the loop right and all of my categories are listed, but what i'm struggling with is to get them inside separate cards - right now they are in the same card. Here's my code

```
<section class="py-5">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                
            <?php   $terms = get_terms( 'deko_category' );
                if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
                echo '<div class="col-md-4">';
                foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                echo '<div style="padding: 30px 45px; background-color: #fff; box-shadow: 
                5px 5px 10px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 5%);">' . $term->name . '</div>';
            }
                echo '</div>';
            }
             ?>             
            </div>
            
        </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

category name : `$category->name` or sub category name : `$subcategory->name`

```
// set taxonomies
$taxonomies = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'taxonomy_name',
    'hide_empty' => false
) );

// if not empty.
if ( !empty($taxonomies) ) :

    foreach( $taxonomies as $category ) {
        // is not parent .
        if( $category->parent == 0 ) {
            foreach( $taxonomies as $subcategory ) {
                if($subcategory->parent == $category->term_id) {
                    echo '<div style="padding: 30px 45px; background-color: #fff; box-shadow: 
                    5px 5px 10px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 5%);">' . $subcategory->name->name . '</div>';
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
endif;
```

Comment: I tried this snippet inside of my section, and it does not render anything unfortunately.